# Stripe+retrieve card fingerprint into this object and array

Tags: php, stripe-payments

Stripe is returning me these values. I wanted to grabe the fingerprint key, how would I do that?

```
Stripe_Card Object
(
    [_apiKey:protected] => sk_test_Deb1234154135135
    [_values:protected] => Array
        (
            [id] => card_17fZAvG8f1zdnddVY72ByeT9
            [object] => card
            [address_city] => 
            [address_country] => 
            [address_line1] => 
            [address_line1_check] => 
            [address_line2] => 
            [address_state] => 
            [address_zip] => 
            [address_zip_check] => 
            [brand] => MasterCard
            [country] => US
            [cvc_check] => pass
            [dynamic_last4] => 
            [exp_month] => 1
            [exp_year] => 2024
            [fingerprint] => KvBrPz5z1SrGYPXk
            [funding] => credit
            [last4] => 4444
            [metadata] => Stripe_AttachedObject Object
                (
                    [_apiKey:protected] => sk_test_DebJYOXQUX66QrP1rEnEb0SA
                    [_values:protected] => Array
                        (
                        )

                    [_unsavedValues:protected] => Stripe_Util_Set Object
                        (
                            [_elts:Stripe_Util_Set:private] => Array
                                (
                                )

                        )

                    [_transientValues:protected] => Stripe_Util_Set Object
                        (
                            [_elts:Stripe_Util_Set:private] => Array
                                (
                                )

                        )

                    [_retrieveOptions:protected] => Array
                        (
                        )

                )

            [name] => John Doe
            [tokenization_method] => 
        )

    [_unsavedValues:protected] => Stripe_Util_Set Object
        (
            [_elts:Stripe_Util_Set:private] => Array
                (
                )

        )

    [_transientValues:protected] => Stripe_Util_Set Object
        (
            [_elts:Stripe_Util_Set:private] => Array
                (
                )

        )

    [_retrieveOptions:protected] => Array
        (
        )

)
```

I tried these codes:

```
$token_details = Stripe_Token::retrieve($token);
echo "<pre>";
print_r($token_details['card']);
die;
```

this wouldn't work. Is there a function in stripe to get the fingerprint key?

Your help will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks! :)

Comment: Even if it's just a test key, you shouldn't share secret API keys. I recommend you edit your message to obfuscate the API key (e.g. `"sk_test_..."` and roll out a new secret API key in your Stripe dashboard: https://dashboard.stripe.com/account/apikeys

Answer (score 1):

`echo $token_details->card->fingerprint`